# Ubuntu 12.04 64bit Can't connect to WPA2 Personal WiFi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 64-bit, wpa2

Recently moved back to Ubuntu from Mint and discovered that Ubuntu doesn't want to connect to my wifi. It just keeps trying and trying, asking for password time after time

**$ sudo lspci -vv -s 02:00.0**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card
Physical Slot: 1
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
Region 0: Memory at d2c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
Capabilities: [60] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <512ns, L1 <64us
        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
    LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+
    DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
    LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
    LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB
Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
    Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
    Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
    Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
    Status: InProgress-
    VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-15-17-ff-ff-24-14-12
Capabilities: [170 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be originated from your modem. I have been where you are (when changing wpa/wpa2 to wep or no auth, it was working) and fixed the problem by changing my modem...

Comment: It worked, a week ago, on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, and without any problem in Mint 15 64bit.

Comment: Did you try to install your your modem driver (maybe)